# Pandas remove line breaks that result in new rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to read a CSV from S3 but some of the individual data fields have erroneous line breaks in it that look like this:

```
|id   |address1      |city      |state|zipcode|
-----------------------------------------------
|12345|123 Street Rd |town      |ST   |12345  |
|     |*line break*  |          |     |       |
|23456|345 Road St   |village   |ST   |34677  |
```

So when I read the dataframe it looks like this:

```
|id   |address1      |city      |state|zipcode|
-----------------------------------------------
|12345|123 Street Rd |          |     |       |
|     |town          |ST        |12345|       |
|23456|345 Road St   |village   |ST   |34677  |
```

What could be causing this? Here is the code I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3

S3Client = boto3.client('s3','us-east-1')

obj = S3Client.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
```

And I have tried to remove the newlines with:

```
df = df.replace(r'\\n',' ', regex=True)
```

to no avail. how should I go about fixing this?

EDIT:

Here is what the data looks like in a text editor:

```
id,address1,city,state,zipcode
12345,"123 Street Rd","town",ST,12345
23456,345 Road St,village,ST,34677
```

updating my code to:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), sep=',', quotechar='"')
```

did not resolve the issue

Here's what it looks like in excel:

[image]

and in a text editor:

[image]

Comment: The csv format has provision for line breaks in fields and Python csv module as well as Pandas gladly support them... provided you declare the exact structure of you file! So please show the csv file **as text** (open it with notepad, vi, emacs or any other text editor) to see what are the delimiter character and the quoting character.

Comment: Edited. Adding the quote character does not solve the issue; weirdly enough there is no newline in the data when I look at it in a text editor

Comment: A csv is a text file. It is no use showing it in Excel because Excel is known to heavily change the csv file. Please show the file as **text**

Comment: Just did! you may notice however that the screen shot from the text editor looks exactly as I typed it in my original edit which is what prompted me to show it in excel.

Comment: There something wrong in the processing. Could you print `obj['Body'].read()`?